# Entity slowing down when reaching the edge of the screen

Tags: java, scroll, libgdx, entity

Here is my Core project :

```
public class GameClass extends Game {

    public static int screenWidth, screenHeight;

    public static CustomScreen currentScreen;
    public static PlayScreen playScreen;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        CustomScreen.initialize();

        playScreen = new PlayScreen(this);

        SetScreen(playScreen);
    }

    public void SetScreen(CustomScreen screen) {
        currentScreen = screen;
        setScreen(currentScreen);
    }
}

public abstract class CustomScreen implements Screen {

    GameClass game;

    static BitmapFont font;
    static SpriteBatch batcher;
    static OrthographicCamera cam;

    public CustomScreen(GameClass game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public static void initialize() {
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(true, GameClass.screenWidth, GameClass.screenHeight);
        batcher = new SpriteBatch();
        batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setScale(4f, -4f);
    }

    public void Clear() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    @Override
    public abstract void render(float delta);
}

public class PlayScreen extends CustomScreen {

    public static final int speed = 300;

    public ArrayList<Entity> entityList;

    Random rand = new Random();
    float timer = rand.nextInt(2) + rand.nextFloat();

    public PlayScreen(GameClass game) {
        super(game);

        entityList = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    }

    void update(float delta) {
        timer -= delta;
        if (timer <= 0) {
            entityList.add(new Enemy(GameClass.screenWidth, rand.nextInt(GameClass.screenHeight - Enemy.Height)));
            timer += rand.nextInt(2) + rand.nextFloat() + 1/2;
        }

        for (int i = entityList.size(); i > 0; --i)
            entityList.get(i-1).update(delta);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Clear();
        update(delta);

        batcher.begin();

        for (int i = 0; i < entityList.size(); ++i) {
            entityList.get(i).Display(batcher);
        }

        if (entityList.size() > 1)
            System.out.println(entityList.get(1).posX - entityList.get(0).posX);

        batcher.end();
    }
}

public abstract class Entity {

    protected Sprite sprite;
    public int posX, posY, width, height;

    public Entity(int posX, int posY, int width, int height) {
        this.posX = posX;
        this.posY = posY;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public abstract void update(float delta);

    public void Display(SpriteBatch batcher) {
        batcher.draw(sprite, posX, posY, width, height);
    }
}

public class Enemy extends Entity {

    static Sprite texture = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("enemy.png")));
    public static int Width = 300, Height = 200;

    public Enemy(int posX, int posY) {
        super(posX, posY, Width, Height);
        this.sprite = Enemy.texture;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float delta, int i) {
        posX -= delta * PlayScreen.speed;

        if (posX + width < 0) {
            GameClass.playScreen.entityList.remove(this);
        }
    }

}
```

In PlayScreen, enemies keep spawning randomly, and they move from the right of the screen to the left, at a **constant speed** (final int 300). But when they reach the left edge of the screen (when posX <= 0), **they slow down**, for an unknown reason. The thing is, **I didn't program anything to happen when an enemy reaches the edge of the screen.** (I programmed them to disappear when they are completely outside of the screen, when posX + width <= 0, but it has nothing to do with my problem, since even when I remove this, they keep slowing down when reaching the edge of the screen).

It happends with both the desktop and the android projects, so this definitely comes from the Core project.

I have no idea why this happens, this is really, really awkward.

Here is a couple picture to show you what happens.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrOSH.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjtju.png

We can see that the two enemies are closer to each other on the second picture than on the first one.

You can set PlayScreen.speed to 100 instead of 300, it will be even more noticeable.
And **if you set it to a low enough value**, like 20, enemies will not just slow down, **they will basically stop moving**.

I'm lost and have no idea how to fix this problem. If you have any, please feel free to share it.

Comment: Your images appear to be broken.

Comment: What do you mean ? You can't see them ?

Comment: They are just empty for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was that Enemy.posX was an int instead of a float.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite certain but I'd guess that your calculations in the Enemy class involving `delta` get rounded (since `PlayScreen.Speed` is an integer).

Having a low enough `PlayScreen.Speed` or a low enough `delta` will result in `delta * PlayScreen.Speed` being 0.something which will get cut off to 0 when converting to an integer, resulting in `posX` never changing.

I usually use floats for all calculations involving positions (e.g. `posX` and `posY` and so on...) so that this cutting off doesn't happen until something gets drawn on the screen (since pixels are always integers). This produces more accurate results and solves a lot of problems around movement on the screen.

Comment: I changed PlayScreen.speed to float, and it didn't change anything. And delta * speed should have (and actually does have ; when I print its value, it doesn't change when the enemy slows down or stops) the same value, whether the enemy has reached the edge of the screen or not.

Comment: I found the problem ! It was indeed because of an integer, but it came from Enemy.posX, and not PlayScreen.speed. Once Enemy.posX is a float, everything works perfeclty.Thanks for your help ! =)

Comment: That's what I meant with the last paragraph ^.^ You should just use floats for everything and only cast to int once you're drawing to the screen. I edited my answer a bit to clarify.